# What command for showing disk usage of specific directory non recursive?

Tags: disk-usage

Can I show how much disk space a directory's contents are using, not including its sub directories (and their contents)?  If so, what commands(s) please?  Thanks.

Comment: du -sh /etc  < example

Comment: perhaps someone can expand on that, explain the parts, and post it as an answer that can be accepted?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Excerpt of `du --help`:

```
-h, --human-readable  print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
-S, --separate-dirs   do not include size of subdirectories
-s, --summarize       display only a total for each argument
```

Running:

```
du -Shs /path/to/dir
```

should give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks.  When I asked that question, I hadn't yet discovered the wonder that awaits with "--help" on many commands :)

Comment: Wow that was a lot easier than I thought. `--separate-dirs` I've never heard of.